# I'm getting error 401 (unauthorized) while trying to make a GET request from my API that has a JWT token

Tags: api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, get, jwt

Here is my GETRequest method...

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var dashboardEndpoint = Helper.GetUsersurl;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer"+Helper.userprofile.token);

            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(dashboardEndpoint);
            var UsersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddedUsers>(result);
            //Users = new ObservableCollection<AddedUsers>(UsersList);

            Emplist.ItemsSource = UsersList.data;

        }
```

I've tried different method but the token isn't being sent alongside my request and therefore the API is throwing an error 401 at me. Any help will be gladly appreciated please...

Comment: have you tried adding a space between "Bearer" and the token?

Comment: please add `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));` above `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i later studied the pattern and also the response on postman then i realize I'm supposed to pass only the key and the value. In this context,

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var dashboardEndpoint = Helper.GetUsersurl;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", Helper.userprofile.token);

            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(dashboardEndpoint);
            var UsersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddedUsers>(result);
            //Users = new ObservableCollection<AddedUsers>(UsersList);

            Emplist.ItemsSource = UsersList.data;
```

I only needed to pass Authorization as the key and token as the value. thanks everyone

Comment: Ok, please do not forget to mark your reply as answer after three days, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @jason said, try to add a space between **Bearer** and the **Token**

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Helper.userprofile.token);
```